# Sha'ir Runesmith - how would rune magic work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, spellcasting, prestige-class

I am building a Runesmith based on a Sha'ir base. Everything works fine, except for the two main abilities, I don't fully understand how to combine them in practice.

> Sha'ir Spellcasting: A sha'ir decides what spell might be useful and sends out his familiar to retrieve it from the elemental planes. To do this, the sha'ir must summon his gen and tell it the name of the spell he seeks. The gen immediately plane shifts to seek the spell in the elemental planes. (...)
>
> If the sha'ir succeeds at his Diplomacy check the gen reappears within 5 feet of its master and imparts to him the power to cast the spell. If the check fails, the gen reappears with no spell. A failure by 5 or more results in the gen being detained for an additional 1d4 minutes.
> Spells retrieved by the gen remain available to the sha'ir to cast for 1 hour per sha'ir level. If a spell is not used within that time, the power to cast the spell dissipates harmlessly.

And in the Runesmith features:

> Rune Magic (Ex): A runesmith learns to prepare his arcane spells as runes inscribed on solid objects (usually small tablets of stone, but other objects are possible). He prepares **spells as normal**, except that instead of readying the spells in his mind, he readies them in the form of runes. Preparing daily spells **takes the same amount of time** as normal preparation and requires the same amount of rest beforehand. A runesmith can leave spell slots unprepared to scribe runes at a later time, just as a wizard can leave spell slots unprepared and fill them later. A runesmith who casts a spell prepared in rune form can cast it with out any somatic component. However, all spells cast from rune form automatically have a material component (the rune itself). In casting the spell, the rune is erased from the tablet, just as a spell cast normally by a wizard is erased from his mind. A runesmith cannot get around the runic material component by means of an ability or feat such as Eschew Materials, although he can use such feats and abilities to waive any other material components for a spell he prepares in rune form, subject to the limitations of the ability. In all other ways, spells prepared in rune form are treated identically to spells prepared in the normal method. A runesmith can still prepare and cast his spells in the regular fashion if he so desires, subject to the normal arcane spell failure chances for any armor worn.

Combining these two class features, would it mean that a Sha'ir charges a rune in no time ( he receives it in the round the gen gets back  and can cast it in the next)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it means that the gen fills the Rune instead of filling the mind of the Sha'ir.

The incorrect assumption in asking the question was that I assumed, that in case of the Sha'ir, the gen getting the spell is a prerequisite for the spell to be prepared in the Sha'irs mind. Whereas it itself is the preparation. In the description the imparting is analogous to the outcome of preparation of a wizard.

> *imparts to him the power to cast the spell*

Now considering the description of rune magic:

> *he prepares spells as normal, except that instead of readying the spells in his mind, he readies them in the form of runes.*

This means, that the gen readies the spell in a rune instead of a the Sha'irs mind, who as part of the Rune Magic feature can casting from that spell.

Rules aside, I really like the idea of a tiny elemental outsider imparting a spell onto a small stone, and the Sha'ir using that to cast the spell. Like the fire gen creating a burning sigil.